# Martini 3 CG water cluster is not becoming spherical under NVT conditions

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs, martini

When we put a certain number of molecules in a small cubic box, and put it inside a large cubic box, under NVT simulation, the water cubic box is supposed to be spherical in shape to reach a minimum energy state. However, the Martini 3 water is not becoming spherical at all. Is this an issue with Martini 3 water, though obviously, CG representation of water is a coarser version? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the pressure, and then performing an NPT at that average pressure, and comparing the density with that of the NVT?

Comment: I want to say I have heard there are quirky things with Martini, and have seen heated debates, where basically one side says it is rubbish... but that said, I don't use it. If it isn't consistent between NPT and NVT though, toss it out.

Comment: periodic boundary conditions are turned off right?

Comment: No answers to B. Kelly's questions?